# Typescript redux set dispatch type

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux

I'm a newbie to typescript and I've been wondering which type to give to dispatch. Right now I've got any, but how could I map all the actions to it?

This is how it looks like:

```
interface PropTypes {
  title: string;
  generalActions: any;
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: any) => ({
  generalActions: bindActionCreators(GeneralActions, dispatch)
});
```

my types file:

```
export const ADD_PROJECT = "ADD_PROJECT";
export const DELETE_PROJECT = "DELETE_PROJECT";
export const CHANGE_TITLE = "CHANGE_TITLE";

export interface Project {
  title: string;
  subtitle: string;
}

export interface ChangeTitleAction {
  type: typeof CHANGE_TITLE;
  title: string;
}
// STATE
export interface ProjectsState {
  projects: Project[];
}

export interface GeneralState {
  title: string;
}

export type GeneralActionTypes = ChangeTitleAction;

export type ProjectActionTypes = AddProjectAction | DeleteProjectAction;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
const dispatch: React.Dispatch<ProjectActionTypes | GeneralActionTypes>;

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  generalActions: bindActionCreators(GeneralActions, dispatch)
});
```